# how to read text file specifications row and column in c#

Tags: c#, text-files

i want read the each row and column but why it will pop out error message "make sure that the maximum index on a list is less than the list size".pls help...

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] line = lines[i].Split('^');
            for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
            {
                textBox1.Text = line[1];

                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why `textBox1.Text = line[1];`? Use `line[j]`.

Comment: The `break;` indicates that there should be a condition for the assignment statement...?

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanted to have `j` in the line

```
textBox1.Text = line[j];
```

instead of

```
textBox1.Text = line[1];
```

Or it won't work if there's more than one part in the line split by `^`.

---

Full code:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] line = lines[i].Split('^');
        for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = line[j];

            break;
        }
    }
```

---

You may also consider changing the line `textBox1.Text = line[j];` as it will overwrite the text in the loop.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment below, the code to read the first column from the first row is:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.txt");
if (lines.Length > 0)
{
    string[] line = lines[0].Split('^');
    if (line.Length > 0)
        textBox1.Text = line[0];
}
```

Comment: if i want read each column and display to different text box?

Comment: You can use the loop code and select the proper text box in there.

Comment: example text file is row1 {ab cd ef} row2 {dc fc fd} row3 {dg hj ki} so output should be textbox1 = column 1 textbox2 = column 2 textbox3 = column 3

Comment: What exactly do you mean by column1, column2?

Comment: textbox1 assign column1 value, textbox2 assign column2 value

Comment: But column 1 for first line only?

Comment: column 1 is for all line

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have an empty line or a line without `^`. Because your accessing the **second** item in the array of strings here:

```
textBox1.Text = line[1];
```

perhaps you want to access always the first element, then use `0` since indices are zero based:

```
textBox1.Text = line[0];
```

However, more meaningful would be

```
textBox1.Text += line[j];
```

Since you are looping the columns anyway.

---

> but i just want read row 1 and col 1 ...so how ??

Then you don't need a loop at all:

```
string firstLinesColumnOne = lines.Length > 0 ? lines[0].Split('^')[0] : "";
textBox1.Text = firstLinesFirstColumn;
```

> if i want read each column and display to different text box? example
>   text file is row1 {ab cd ef} row2 {dc fc fd} row3 {dg hj ki} so output
>   should be textbox1 = column 1 textbox2 = column 2 textbox3 = column 3

Assuming you want to assign split three columns to three textboxes and add a new line for every line in the file in the textbox as well:

```
IEnumerable<String[]> lineColumns = lines
    .Select(line => line.Split('^'));
textBox1.Lines = lineColumns.Select(cols => cols[0]).ToArray();
textBox2.Lines = lineColumns.Select(cols => cols[1]).ToArray();
textBox3.Lines = lineColumns.Select(cols => cols[2]).ToArray();
```

Comment: if i want read each column and display to different text box?

Comment: How many TextBoxes do you have? I mean, the number of columns could change but the number of controls normally is fixed. Maybe you should use  a `ListBox` instead. However, you can access each column via indexer, either directly or in a loop. So you could add items to a `ListBox` in a loop for example.

Comment: example text file is
row1 {ab cd ef}
row2 {dc fc fd}
row3 {dg hj ki}
so output should be
textbox1 = column 1
textbox2 = column 2
textbox3 = column 3

Comment: @CCY: You have three lines with three columns, so 9 fields for three textboxes. What do you want to use for which column?

Comment: column1 for name, column 2 for phmun, column 3 for date...so i want assign each of column to each text box...

Comment: @CCY: Ok, but you have multiple lines, so these lines should be separate lines in each textbox too?

Comment: @CCY: Do you want to overwerite the old text on each line, which would be pointless since you wouldnt see the old value, or do you want to add it to a new line?

Comment: @CCY: However, i've edited my answer to provide one approach which assigns one line in each TextBox for every line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = line[1];
```

if `line.Length == 1` there is no `line[1]`, there is only `line[0]`